# How to prevent horizontal scrolling after clicking anchor link

Tags: html, css

I have a simple design with a hoverable index menu with anchor link and a main block of content in a fix width. When the index menu is shown, I set the main block to have a margin equal to the width of the index menu, so the index will not block the content. However when the window is narrow the total width of the menu and the main content exceed the window width, causing the page scroll horizontally after clicking the anchor links.

I would like to prevent this horizontal scrolling after clicking the links. I want the main content to have a fix width thus the solution in [Damià's answser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77840635/#77841369) is less ideal for me.

Here is a mini example of the situation I encounter:

```css
body{
  

  background: black;
}

nav{
  position: fixed;
  
  background: white;
}

nav:hover #menu{
  display: block;
}

nav:hover ~ main{
  margin: 0 0 0 400px;
}

nav #menu{
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
}

main{
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
<nav>
  <div id="hoverable">
    <p>
    hover
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#anchor1">anchor1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#anchor2">anchor2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<main>
  <h1 id="anchor1">
  Some title
  </h1>
  <p>
  Won't creeping our form stars hath have replenish. Whales behold own said There is. Own. Isn't created fish from dominion heaven tree kind image fill after shall make. Blessed divide. Make meat don't. Second doesn't created void you're. Evening lesser open bearing the called green great give heaven subdue may given rule earth hath without. Heaven replenish image creeping that for his be without signs sixth you lesser tree behold also blessed night years divided evening. Lesser have creepeth that. Is divide very bring she'd, is itself thing heaven in midst. Living wherein to there saw lights signs winged signs don't. Female have meat. Give said signs light. Green green god evening good divided male moveth together moved. Blessed creeping have fill winged light made moving gathering living great kind Hath fourth. It void whose moving midst fish called us lights yielding be void bring. Sea fish signs a and for divide. Bearing and lesser. After face lights stars.

Us it stars tree was place face life, earth that, may you'll the their. Saw meat give. And wherein our male seed fish creeping gathering after air sea fifth he deep air give evening under. Days. Blessed. Fly. Cattle great tree thing likeness unto creepeth saw over fruit Land beast gathered wherein firmament won't stars fly saw herb bring creepeth day itself, him lights were Under make. Won't fruit. Made good morning had fourth and divided lights cattle, morning female. Were Likeness divide can't also you're saying subdue air two second fruit have don't, fill days Given fruit Female likeness. Forth earth likeness moving there. Brought spirit multiply you'll above. Cattle he, every. Fish. Their their in and is you're face morning they're you'll together third firmament very, doesn't forth, may set place heaven i grass green gathering i. Make. Morning above great it sea they're fill divided face darkness above, may from to form. Seas. Divided void give be, brought. Multiply firmament us firmament fourth made creepeth he he light face behold let lesser was bearing winged them great lights stars from their.

Fifth dry meat herb in created itself subdue whales. That saw forth him have night made set can't creeping creepeth all hath greater night lights under that great to their after shall i sea you're from may waters god third fly set above likeness face said, you'll life can't beginning land god first won't heaven forth living, a place can't. Dominion face have be life sixth which. Creepeth. Beast was creepeth green signs fish it signs light thing he second own. Deep. In midst they're fourth the man blessed divided fruitful can't. Face sixth a spirit air divided. Fifth appear from. A one may doesn't. Created there divide The his and their deep abundantly seas fish saying were sea likeness hath. Sea you'll. Itself they're herb, also, had his he he brought. Hath you. May above make. Fill given gathering us fly image a multiply lights made likeness won't greater upon upon behold light won't sixth fly.
  </p>
  
  <h1 id="anchor2">
  Anchor2
  </h1>
  <p>
  Won't creeping our form stars hath have replenish. Whales behold own said There is. Own. Isn't created fish from dominion heaven tree kind image fill after shall make. Blessed divide. Make meat don't. Second doesn't created void you're. Evening lesser open bearing the called green great give heaven subdue may given rule earth hath without. Heaven replenish image creeping that for his be without signs sixth you lesser tree behold also blessed night years divided evening. Lesser have creepeth that. Is divide very bring she'd, is itself thing heaven in midst. Living wherein to there saw lights signs winged signs don't. Female have meat. Give said signs light. Green green god evening good divided male moveth together moved. Blessed creeping have fill winged light made moving gathering living great kind Hath fourth. It void whose moving midst fish called us lights yielding be void bring. Sea fish signs a and for divide. Bearing and lesser. After face lights stars.

Us it stars tree was place face life, earth that, may you'll the their. Saw meat give. And wherein our male seed fish creeping gathering after air sea fifth he deep air give evening under. Days. Blessed. Fly. Cattle great tree thing likeness unto creepeth saw over fruit Land beast gathered wherein firmament won't stars fly saw herb bring creepeth day itself, him lights were Under make. Won't fruit. Made good morning had fourth and divided lights cattle, morning female. Were Likeness divide can't also you're saying subdue air two second fruit have don't, fill days Given fruit Female likeness. Forth earth likeness moving there. Brought spirit multiply you'll above. Cattle he, every. Fish. Their their in and is you're face morning they're you'll together third firmament very, doesn't forth, may set place heaven i grass green gathering i. Make. Morning above great it sea they're fill divided face darkness above, may from to form. Seas. Divided void give be, brought. Multiply firmament us firmament fourth made creepeth he he light face behold let lesser was bearing winged them great lights stars from their.

Fifth dry meat herb in created itself subdue whales. That saw forth him have night made set can't creeping creepeth all hath greater night lights under that great to their after shall i sea you're from may waters god third fly set above likeness face said, you'll life can't beginning land god first won't heaven forth living, a place can't. Dominion face have be life sixth which. Creepeth. Beast was creepeth green signs fish it signs light thing he second own. Deep. In midst they're fourth the man blessed divided fruitful can't. Face sixth a spirit air divided. Fifth appear from. A one may doesn't. Created there divide The his and their deep abundantly seas fish saying were sea likeness hath. Sea you'll. Itself they're herb, also, had his he he brought. Hath you. May above make. Fill given gathering us fly image a multiply lights made likeness won't greater upon upon behold light won't sixth fly.
  </p>
</main>
</body>
```

see it on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yr85h10t/5/

Comment: The margins aren't changing, the window is just being scrolled right to bring the linked element into view. Is that what you are describing?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also revise your question post to present the problem _before_ your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

What actually happens is that the page scrolls horizontally when there is no space left for the main div and user clicks an anchor.
This is because you add a width of 60vw to the main class. It's better if you change it to something related to the actual space left.
For example you can use this:

```
 width: calc (100% - 400px);
```

The 400px are for the left margin.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! now I understand what's happening. I would like a way to prevent this horizontal scroll rather then change the width if possible tho, I have update the question with more info and updated snippet